# How do I open a new github project in MacOS PyCharm without closing everything?

Tags: macos, pycharm

Have been using PyCharm for a few years but still cannot figure out this. Basically I have a few projects open and I want to clone a new github project and open that in a new window. I don't see any option to do that. "Open" only open local folders, "Open Recent" of course does not show projects I never cloned, and everything under "Git" is only for the current project.

The only way seems to be closing everything, and PyCharm shows a window where I can clone a new project. What did I miss? This is such a trivial requirement that I refuse to think that Jetbrain misses it. It must be somewhere, just not that obvious, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. In another answer someone shows a screenshot that it can be achieved by choosing "Get from version control" under "VCS". Unfortunately I don't even see "VCS". The ultimate solution, at least for me, is to goto keymap configuration, find this "Get from version control", setup a key shortcut and then it works as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no citation needed. You can follow the descriptions precisely and get what you want.